# Create multiple plots from multiple dataframes (not ggplot) in r

Tags: r, loops, plot

Hello, I have a large dataframe which I split following the next code:

```
DF2 <- split(df, df$Species)
        new_names <- as.character(unique(df$Species))
    for (i in 1:length(DF2)) {
      assign(new_names[i], DF2[[i]])
    }
```

Giving me many dataframes with each having the same starting letters DF2Fish-XX with the XX being the unique species:

Now I want to have a loop function to create multiple plots using the following code to  for each Species (unique dataframe):

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
DF2Plot <- function(index){plot(DF2Fish-XX[,index] ~ DF2Fish-XX$Year, 
                          main=names(DF2Fish-XX[index]), xlab= "Years", 
                          ylab = "Trophic position", type="b", xlim=range(1930:2020), ylim=range(2:5))}
lapply(2:5, FUN= DF2Plot)
```

Is there a way to have the second part of the script (creating the plot) in a loop for each unique species/dataframe created in the first part of code?

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should try to use the list of data frames for each species that you created: `lapply(DF2, function(data) plot(y ~ x, data = data, main = unique(data$Species), ...))`

Comment: How can I make them visible? each species separate ;)

Comment: For @rawr's comment, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227, *many* good examples of working with data in a list of frames.

Comment: you already have a list of data frames with each species separate, so when you run `plot(...)` in the `lapply`, you will get a new plot for each species

Comment: Is there a way for me to extract them separately afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll demonstrate using `iris`.

```r
irisL <- split(iris, iris$Species)
names(irisL)
# [1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica" 
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for (nm in names(irisL)) {
  plot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=irisL[[nm]], main=nm)
}
```

[image: iris separated plots]

If your list of frames is not named, then you can index this way:

```r
for (ind in seq_along(irisL)) {
  # ...
}
```

though you will need a direct way to infer the name (perhaps `as.character(irisL[[ind]]$Species[1])`).